# How to find word after match containing Swedish characters in python 2.7

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, character-encoding

For a few days i have been struggling to get a function to work. I want to search for the word "Ort : " ( ort = city in English) and get the word after that. Works great with words without Swedish åäö. It doesn't matter if i read a line from a file written windows machine or i create a file with vim. It the "Ort" contains åäö the search comes back empty. I have tried many types of encoding and sometimes i get error but not the results i want. A text can look like this
"Brand i byggnad Ort : Örebro alla ute" and the funtion looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
__author__ = 'stefan'
import re
import codecs
import findloc
from findloc import findloc
# tried different ways open file
#testfil = open('extra.flt.test', 'r')
#testfil =  codecs.open('/medianas/html/extra.flt.hist', 'r', '1250')
testfil =  codecs.open('extra.flt.klar', 'r', 'latin1')
#testfil =  codecs.open('/medianas/html/pocsaglog.flt', 'r', '1250')
keyword = 'Ort :'
for line in testfil:
    line = line.decode('utf8')
# Find word after Ort :
    ort = re.search(r'\Ort : (\w+)', line)
# Find word after Adr :
    adr = re.search(r'\Adr : (\w+)', line)
    if adr:
        print adr.group(1)
        adress = adr.group(1)
        cord = findloc(adress)
        lat = (cord[0])
        lng = (cord[1])
    if ort:
        print ort.group(1)
        stad = ort.group(1)
        cord = findloc(stad)
        lat = (cord[0])
        lng = (cord[1])
testfil.close()
```

I hope someone can help me or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken the liberty to cut down your example according to 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

For your problem, try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

line="Brand i byggnad Ort : Örebro alla ute"

# Find word after Ort :
ort = re.search('Ort : (.*)', line)
print ort.groups()[0].split(' ')[0]
```

Comment: The place name in this example is "Örebro"; the phrase "alla ute" is a status message regarding this fire alert. In the general case it's hard to know how many tokens to extract after the "Ort:" token (which properly speaking should not have a space before the colon in Swedish, either). To grab only the next word, try `(\w+)`. To grab any words which start with an uppercase letter, try `([A-ZÅÄÖ][a-zåäö]*(?:\s+[A-ZÅÄÖ][a-zåäö]*))`. Depending on your use case, maybe add `üéæø` etc to the character classes. (Unfortunately, Python does not provide a convenient way to say "any Unicode uppercase".)